# How to use dart to implement a delegate/proxy?

Tags: proxy, delegates, dart, dart-mirrors, nosuchmethod

I have two classes `Parser` and `Proxy`, and when I invoke a method from `Parser`, which does not exist, it will delegate it to `Proxy` class.

My code:

```dart
class Parser {
    noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
        // how to pass the `invocation` to `Proxy`???
    }
}

class Proxy {
    static String hello() { return "hello"; }
    static String world() { return "world"; }
}
```

That when I write:

```dart
var parser = new Parser();
print(parser.hello());
```

It will print:

```
hello
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use *dart:mirrors*. Here's how to do :

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Parser {
  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
    ClassMirror cm = reflectClass(Proxy);
    return cm.invoke(invocation.memberName
        , invocation.positionalArguments
        /*, invocation.namedArguments*/ // not implemented yet
        ).reflectee;
  }
}

class Proxy {
  static String hello() { return "hello"; }
  static String world() { return "world"; }
}

main(){
  var parser = new Parser();
  print(parser.hello());
  print(parser.world());
}
```

Comment: Can I use `cm.delegate(invocation)` instead of `cm.invoke(...)`? I tried they both working, but what's the difference?

Comment: Unlike [InstanceMirror](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_mirrors/InstanceMirror.html), there's no `delegate` method on [ClassMirror](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_mirrors/ClassMirror.html). You can [file an issue for that](http://dartbug.com/new).

Answer (score 7):

Alexandre's answer is correct, but I'd like to add something.

I assume that the delegation to `Proxy` is an implementation detail, and we don't want the user to be exposed to it. In that case, we should have some handling of cases where methods are called on `parser` that are not supported by `Proxy`. Right now, if you do this:

```dart
void main() {
  var parser = new Parser();
  print(parser.foo());
}
```

You get this error:

```dart
Unhandled exception:
Compile-time error during mirrored execution: <Dart_Invoke: did not find static method 'Proxy.foo'.>
```

I would write the code in `noSuchMethod` a little differently. Before delegating to `Proxy`, I would check that `Proxy` supports the method I'm about to invoke. If `Proxy` supports it, I would invoke the method on `Proxy` as Alexandre describes in his answer. If `Proxy` does not support the method, I would throw a `NoSuchMethodError`.

Here is a revised version of the answer:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Parser {
  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
    ClassMirror cm = reflectClass(Proxy);
    if (cm.methods.keys.contains(invocation.memberName)) {
      return cm.invoke(invocation.memberName
          , invocation.positionalArguments
          /*, invocation.namedArguments*/ // not implemented yet
          ).reflectee;
    }
    throw new NoSuchMethodError(this,
        _symbolToString(invocation.memberName),
        invocation.positionalArguments,
        _symbolMapToStringMap(invocation.namedArguments));
  }
}


String _symbolToString(Symbol symbol) => MirrorSystem.getName(symbol);

Map<String, dynamic> _symbolMapToStringMap(Map<Symbol, dynamic> map) {
  if (map == null) return null;
  var result = new Map<String, dynamic>();
  map.forEach((Symbol key, value) {
    result[_symbolToString(key)] = value;
  });
  return result;
}

class Proxy {
  static String hello() { return "hello"; }
  static String world() { return "world"; }
}

main(){
  var parser = new Parser();
  print(parser.hello());
  print(parser.world());
  print(parser.foo());
}
```

And here is the output from running this code:

```dart
hello
world
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'foo'
Receiver: Instance of 'Parser'
Arguments: []
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll also add that you could avoid the use of mirrors if the set of things you want to delegate to is fixed and you can reasonably hard-code it. That's particularly easy if you're using static methods, but I'm not clear why you're doing that here. I think the following would work for both instance methods and static methods, but I'm typing this code in without actually trying it...

```dart
Function lookupMethod(Proxy p, Symbol name) {
  if (name == const Symbol("hello")) return p.hello;
  if (name == const Symbol("world")) return p.world;
  throw "Aaaaaagh";
}

noSuchMethod(invocation) => 
    Function.apply(lookupMethod(Proxy, invocation.memberName),
        invocation.positionalArguments);
```

This is fragile if the set of forwarded methods changes, but may help avoid the code size increase if you use mirrors (which at the moment disables almost all tree-shaking).

Answer (score 2):

This example also may help you to understand:

```dart
void main() {
  var car = new CarProxy(new ProxyObjectImpl('Car'));
  testCar(car);

  var person = new PersonProxy(new ProxyObjectImpl('Person'));
  testPerson(person);
}

void testCar(Car car) {
  print(car.motor);
}

void testPerson(Person person) {
  print(person.age);
  print(person.name);
}

abstract class Car {
  String get motor;
}

abstract class Person {
  int get age;
  String get name;
}

class CarProxy implements Car {
  final ProxyObject _proxy;

  CarProxy(this._proxy);

  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
    return _proxy.handle(invocation);
  }
}

class PersonProxy implements Person {
  final ProxyObject _proxy;

  PersonProxy(this._proxy);

  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
    return _proxy.handle(invocation);
  }
}

abstract class ProxyObject {
  dynamic handle(Invocation invocation);
}

class ProxyObjectImpl implements ProxyObject {
  String type;
  int id;
  Map<Symbol, dynamic> properties;

  ProxyObjectImpl(this.type, [this.id]) {
    properties = ProxyManager.getProperties(type);
  }

  dynamic handle(Invocation invocation) {
    var memberName = invocation.memberName;

    if(invocation.isGetter) {
      if(properties.containsKey(memberName)) {
        return properties[memberName];
      }
    }

    throw "Runtime Error: $type has no $memberName member";
  }
}

class ProxyManager {
  static Map<Symbol, dynamic> getProperties(String name) {
    Map<Symbol, dynamic> properties = new Map<Symbol, dynamic>();
    switch(name) {
      case 'Car':
        properties[new Symbol('motor')] = 'xPowerDrive2013';
        break;
      case 'Person':
        properties[new Symbol('age')] = 42;
        properties[new Symbol('name')] = 'Bobby';
        break;
      default:
        throw new StateError('Entity not found: $name');
    }

    return properties;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid creating one proxy per class.