# Is it possible to write a custom networking proxy to the Dart VM and/or Dart AOT mode?

Tags: dart

I'm new to Dart and I'm avaliating possibilities for my project. Since Dart and be both AOT and JIT compiled, I have two questions: in the VM, is it possible to write my own networking rules? For example, suppose I want to intercept my Dart TCP connections for whatever reason (inspecting, proxying, etc). Is it possible?

Is it also possible in the AOT compilation mode?

Comment: Do you mean inside the same application or another standalone application which should work as a proxy?

Comment: @julemand101 inside the same application

Comment: You meant [delegete/proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442581/how-to-use-dart-to-implement-a-delegate-proxy) ?

Comment: @VictorGubin I've read about mirror now and I can't understand how it enabled me to force, for example, Dart's HTTP class to use a custom socket instead of the default one. It it possible?